# Задача на обработку числовой последовательности на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Не понимаю, как решать такие задачи:

> Напишите программу, ко­то­рая в по­сле­до­ва­тель­но­сти целых чисел опре­де­ля­ет их сумму и под­счи­ты­ва­ет количество по­ло­жи­тель­ных чётных чисел, не пре­вос­хо­дя­щих 100.
> Количество чисел не пре­вы­ша­ет 1000. Введённые числа по мо­ду­лю не пре­вы­ша­ют 30 000.

Что с кодом не так?

```
count = 0
total = 0
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    else:

        total += n       
while n > 0 and n%2 == 0 and n<=100:
    count+=n
print(total)    
print(count)
```

Comment: это вы должны сказать что не так. Почему вы думаете, что с кодом что-то не так?

Comment: напишите сначала алгоритм решения на бумаге на русском, а потом переводите его на питонский.

Comment: Тестовая система не принимает мое решение, поэтому думаю, что что-то, очевидно, не так. Если бы я знала, что именно, меня бы сейчас здесь не было -- всё просто.

Comment: ну тогда пройдитесь пошагово по своей программе. Вы ее вообще запускали для проверки? Нет, скорее всего, потому что если бы да, то вы бы и сами не приняли свое решение. Ошибки у вас элементарные и будет лучше, если вы с ними справитесь самостоятельно.

Comment: Потрясающе полезный и ценный комментарий, но я ничего другого здесь и не ожидала.

Comment: если вы не хотите даже попробовать самостоятельно искать ошибки, то зачем вам вообще программирование. А если бы попробовали искать, то уже давным давно бы решили свою проблему. А если вы ничего другого и не ожидали, то зачем же потратили время на написание вопроса?

Comment: Я искала ошибки весь день

Comment: добавьте в цикл while строчку print(n)

Comment: мне просто интересно, а как ответ можно увидеть в этой программе?)

Comment: Попробуйте запустить не в тестовой системе.

Comment: Вы считаете сумму, но не пытаетесь считать *количество по­ло­жи­тель­ных чётных чисел, не пре­вос­хо­дя­щих 100*. Нет такого в вашем цикле...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = 0

Count = 0

while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    sum += n
    if 0 < n <=100 and n%2==0:
        Count += 1


print(sum)

print(Count)
```

Может, кому пригодится.